# Use IsNumeric SQL query via VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

Please find my below VBA code where i am trying to filter only numerical data from below data. but i am not getting the required output. Please suggest me.

[image]

```
Sub SQL()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT [Sheet5$].[Sr], [Ch] FROM [Sheet5$] WHERE IsNumeric([Sheet5$].[ch]) = 1"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sheet5.Range("D1").CopyFromRecordset rs

'Debug.Print rs.GetString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `=1`:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Sheet5$].[Sr], [Ch] FROM [Sheet5$] WHERE IsNumeric([Sheet5$].[ch])"
```